# Should the comments message have trim end applied?

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment character counter does not trim, while the server does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98970/comment-character-counter-does-not-trim-while-the-server-does)

I've noticed while entering comments in the past where they haven't been long enough to submit, that if I include spaces it counts in the message `4 more to go...` but when fulfilling the messages requirements, upon submit the `message not long enough` box appears.

Should the message highlighting how many characters to go be a total of the end trimmed text or stay as it is?

Answer (score 2):

If what I think is right, it keeps counting the trailing spaces expecting a non-space character yet to come. If no such non-space character is added at the end and the comment is submitted, the string is trimmed of trailing spaces and can end up as too short to qualify.

In this case, it shows it's not a good idea to try and workaround the minimum character requirement by simply adding trailing spaces.