# Inconsistent Input Validation

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment character counter does not trim, while the server does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98970/comment-character-counter-does-not-trim-while-the-server-does)

If I enter the comment

> 1  456789012345

(two spaces after the 1)

The text below the comment input box changes from "1 more to go..." to "585 characters left" after I enter the last 5.

However, if I try to submit that comment, I get a popup notification

"Comments must be at least 15 characters in length."

The problem seems to be caused by inconsistent treatment of the double space after the initial 1.

Comment: I always thought this was by design. Consecutive whitespaces are interpreted as an attempt to game the systems, so there's no heads-up when you're trying to do it.

Comment: Sure, but why provide *inconsistent* feedback to the consecutive whitespace?  Just don't count it, in a consistent manner.

Comment: SO has one of the best web interfaces out there. Personally I see this as inconsistent input validation that ever so slightly tarnishes the awesomeness of the overall user experience, not as a "feature" to "get" people who are gaming the counter.